# Whatsapp auth response Error c#

Tags: c#, authentication, whatsapp

I'm creating a whatsapp messenger in winforms c#.
i'm using whatsappapi & getting Auth error
**Details:**

> (Auth response error at WhatsAppApi.WhatsSendBase.addAuthResponse() at
>   WhatsAppApi.WhatsSendBase.Login(Byte[] nextChallenge))

I wanna ask that whatsapp auth api still works (because i have heard that whatsapp banned it)

Comment: If you heard whatsapp banned it, why not google it? Doesn't exactly seem like a question for SO..

Comment: i have googled it but im not getting it